# Jquery masked input -phone number not working while edit

Tags: jquery, phone-number

I'm having a little issue with a masked input with jquery:

I have a phonenumber text input,  I masked it like

```
$("#phone").mask("9999-9999999");
```

It works great but when i am trying to populate value in phone number field while editing,it is not showing.

When I just click reset button it appears.

I am using jquery-1.5.2.min.js and jquery.maskedinput.js - Version: 1.2.2

Comment: Can you setup an example on http://jsbin.com for us?

Comment: Plese tell are you trying to do like this  JSFiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/vnD3b/1/

Comment: @Chinmaya003 yes that working,but while populating results in text field nothing appears.

Comment: @JonathanSampson i have done,please check

Comment: can u provide a jsfiddle exmple for your problem?

Comment: @Chinmaya003 http://jsfiddle.net/vnD3b/4/ pls check

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of masked value like this:

```
$("#tin").mask("9999-9999999").val("11111111");
```

Comment: but how can i dynamically set the value,i mean while taking edit page i want to populate that value

Comment: Please add the solution as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

phone Number field has limited to 11 using mask,and database field also has 11 length.but actually the phone number contains 12 chars(including -).so the phone number was not updating correctly.while populating it on phone field that was the problem